# Golang Kafka Reader cannot read messages from a topic

Tags: go, apache-kafka, segment-io

I have a Kafka ConsumerGroup (Golang/Segmentio) with one reader. The reader is unable to read messages from a topic but I am able to create a writer in the same piece of code and write to the topic from which the reader is unable to read from.

Below is my code for creating a kafka reader:

```
    reader := kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
        Brokers:     []string{"host.docker.internal:9092"},
        GroupID:     kafkaGroupID,
        Topic:       "test-topic",
        MinBytes:    10e3,
        MaxBytes:    10e6,
        StartOffset: kafka.FirstOffset,
    })
```

I tried to configure reader with 'StartOffset' of FirstOffset and LastOffset with no success.

I am running this locally on MacOS. From the kafka docker container logs I was able to verify that the topic was created successfully. I am however able to see the messages in the topic using kafkacat using a different groupID.

I am out of ideas of how to troubleshoot this. Any ideas or tips on what I could be missing or ways to debug would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running this code outside of Docker?

Comment: Also, why are you connecting to the host instead of the kafka container?

Comment: Changed it to kafka:9092 and still seeing the same behavior. I have not tried to run it outside of docker.

Comment: In some cases, the reader seems to read the message after a long wait whereas the kafkacat consumer is able to read it immediately after the write.